# Congruence between Symmetric and non-Symmetric Matrices for Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-congruences

I learned that for a bilinear form/square form the following **theorem** holds:
Matrices  $A,B$ are congruent if and only if $A,B$  represent the same bilinear/quadratic form.

Now, suppose I have the following quadratic form $ q(x,y) = x^2 + 3xy + y^2 $.
Then, the matrix representing this quadratic form can be $ B = \pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 } $ and also $ A = \pmatrix{1 & \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} & 1 } $.
I tried showing that $ A,B$  are congruent, meaning that there exists an invertible matrix $M $ such that $ A = M^T \cdot B \cdot M $ but such matrix $ M $ does not exist, here's the calculation for example:
$ M = \pmatrix{ a & b \\ c & d } $
[image]
And according to Wolfram:
[image]

Yet, $A,B$  represent the same quadratic form, but they are not congruent, so this is a contradiction to the **theorem** above.

**Question:**
How is this possible? These matrices should be congruent since they do represent the same quadratic form.
( I know that for every matrix $A$, $ \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) $ is symmetric, but this doesn't answer why the above congruence fails to hold ).

I mean, the following holds:
$ \pmatrix{ x & y } B\pmatrix{ x \\ y } = \pmatrix{ x & y } \pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 } \pmatrix{ x \\ y } = \pmatrix{ x & y }\pmatrix{x + 3y \\ y } = x(x+3y) +y^2 = x^2 + 3xy + y^2 $

$ \pmatrix{ x & y } A\pmatrix{ x \\ y } = \pmatrix{ x & y } \pmatrix{1 & \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} & 1 } \pmatrix{ x \\ y } = \pmatrix{ x & y }\pmatrix{x + \frac{3}{2}y \\ \frac{3}{2}x+y } = x(x+\frac{3}{2}y) +y(\frac{3}{2}x+y) = x^2 + \frac{3}{2}xy + \frac{3}{2}yx + y^2 = x^2 +3xy+y^2
 $

So $A,B$ represent the same quadratic form.
I know that the quadratic form has only a unique symmetric matrix that represents it, in this case it is $A$ but this still doesn't answer why the above congruence between $A,B$ fails to hold ( it should hold because they represent the same quadratic form )

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Matrix representations of symmetric bilinear forms are assumed to be symmetric. So, the $A$ and $B$ in the theorem you mentioned are supposed to be symmetric. You don't need a computer algebra system to check that a symmetric $A$ is not congruent to a non-symmetric $B$, because when $A$ is symmetric, $X^TAX$ is necessarily symmetric and hence it cannot possibly be equal to $B$!

Comment: So what if I don't use this assumption and one of my matrices is not symmetric? this means I won't be able to find a change of basis matrix that lets $A$ to  become $B$ ( since $ B = P^{-1}AP  $ is not symmetric and it should be since $ A $ is symmetric, so this is a contradiction ) and most theorems I learned about quadratic forms fail to hold ( like the one given above about the congruence between $A,B$ )?

Comment: Yes, the theorems will fail to hold if you don't assume symmetry.

Comment: Ok thanks, everything clear now!